# Replacement for pgnscid

Tags: scid

Last **Scid** versions come without **pgnscid** shipped with it. That happens since version 4.6.0, when it was removed because it was stated as *obsolete*, according to changelog.

I guess that if **pgnscid** is now obsolete must be because another executable can be used to do what the former did, a command line utility to convert a pgn file into a scid database, but I'm not able to find out how to do it with the other executables packed with **Scid**.

Does anybody have a clue on which is **pgnscid** replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pgnscid does not have a replacement. Instead, it is expected that you import the pgn file within a SCID database.